# How do I get the users input to fetch the api url?

Tags: javascript, api, input, fetch-api, weather-api

```
//OpenWeather Info
const weatherKey = '*********';
const weatherURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'

//Page Elements
const input = document.querySelector("#input").value;
const button = document.querySelector('#submit');

//Fetch
const getWeather = async () => {
    try {
        const apiURL = weatherURL+ "?&q=" + input + "&APPID=" + weatherKey;
        console.log(apiURL);
        const response = await fetch(apiURL);
        if (response.ok) {
            const jsonResponse = await response.json();
            console.log(jsonResponse);
            return jsonResponse;
        } else {
            console.log("request failed!");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
**}**

const renderWeather = (data) => {
    document.querySelector("#weather-degrees").innerHTML = data.main.temp;
}

const executeSearch = () => {
    getWeather().then(data => renderWeather(data));
}

button.addEventListener('click', executeSearch());
```

I can't get the value of input when I type in the textbox and it won't fetch the apiURL. Before I even type in anything the console gives me this. Any help?
[console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m12J.png)

Comment: You have to read the input value right before you call the fetch function!

Comment: You should be careful posting API keys online, even if you're using the free tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` is set **once** beforehand. Instead, do something like:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
// ...
const apiURL = weatherURL+ "?&q=" + input.value + "&APPID=" + weatherKey;
// or using a template literal
const apiURL = `${weatherURL}?&q=${input.value}&APPID=${weatherKey}`;
```

*Mind that you should also [URL encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the input.*

Since `input` is only set once now, it's set to an empty string. You can directly visit the API url, i.e. https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=82510feaa0c1d3a300a7a754ff134404&q= and notice that it doesn't work. If you replace `q=` with a proper value, e.g. `q=London`, it will work fine.

Mind that the API will also return a 400 error (but with a different error message) if you pass it an invalid city. Read the error from the reponse body and properly display an error to the user about invalid input.

Comment: So I did what you said using template literal and having the input.value inside the apiURL but it's still giving me the same error. It's still trying to fetch at start even when I freshly reload it. Also still doesn't recieve the value when I type in the box and click submit.

Comment: Did you also update your `const input` to not immediately read `.value`?

Comment: Yes, I switched it to what you said with `const input = document.querySelector("#input");`

Comment: Oh I didn't notice you were also doing `button.addEventListener('click', executeSearch());`. You're basically calling `executeSearch()` and say "whenever button gets clicked, call the result" _(which is not `executeSearch` itself)_. You should use `button.addEventListener('click', executeSearch);` instead.

Comment: Okay that worked but now when I type something and submit nothing logs out and changes.

Comment: That seems like another issue then, separate from this input variable one. Try debugging (either using breakpoints or using `console.log` statements) and see what does (not) get called. Worst case, if you can't find anything after debugging and researching, create a new question.

Comment: When I click submit I see the log for a quick second and it just dissappears. I checked the preserve logs and says TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Then there's something else wrong with your code. Mark this answer as the solution to your question (about the wrong URL and `input` variable) and make a new one where you explain how your code doesn't execute even though it logs in certain places.